# Intel DAAL possible issue with header file?

Tags: c++, intel, intel-parallel-studio, intel-dal

I installed Intel parallel studio on Mac OS and using daal to build my files. After setting up the variable, and run,

```
daalvars.sh intel64
icc my_first_daal_program.cpp -daal=parallel -o my_first_daal_program
```

I got following error

```
my_first_daal_program.cpp(1): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "daal.h"
#include <daal.h>
                ^
compilation aborted for my_first_daal_program.cpp (code 4)
```

Does this mean the header file is not located?

Answer (score 1):

You should set environment like this:

```
. daalvars.sh intel64
```

for the settings to stay visible for following command.